# I am running Knoppix on my desktop. How do I switch to Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

Probably a really simple solution, but I can't figure out how to install Ubuntu onto a system running Knoppix.  I don't want a dual boot, just want to replace Knoppix with Ubuntu.  Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

Just do a fresh install of Ubuntu on the same machine.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

(You may want to back up `/home` first, if you have files there you want to keep.)